# Editing your own answer

Tags: discussion, iterative-review

As an example, consider [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/538/random-number-generator-class/550#550).
One of the comments I had on the code posted asked whether a method needed to be public. A comment was posted stating that in this context the method in question was usually made public.

I am certain that this type of discussion will happen often. StackOverflow promotes editing for correctness, but this isn't a matter of correctness. It's more of convention or style.

I think that my answer should not be edited to remove my comment, but should remain and the comments be used to further discuss the suggestion. It seems that this would be in the best spirit of a code review, where ideas and opinions can flow freely to produce the clearest, best code. Also, future visitors can more easily follow the conversation and understand the thought processes involved.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with this.  Also edits to a question happen (due to feedback), we should try to ensure they get put into their own edit block so the original is preserved and there is some sort of continuity to the entire thing.